# PHP Array - obtaining vlaues

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, the output of print_r is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [col1] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [col1] => 2 ) )
```

Could you help of kind of array it is? So that I could research more about it? What I want is to get `ID` and `col1` values

I've tried to use foreach:

```
foreach($array_name as $key=>$value){
     print "$key holds $value\n";
 }
```

The output I get is `0 holds Array 1 holds Array` 
And I would simply like to get:

```
1 1
2 2
```

Comment: So you just want to loop through this array?

Comment: You're array is a multidimensional array! Please read the manual about arrays!

Comment: You can just loop it, via `foreach ($array_name as $arr)`, and your values are `$arr['ID']` and `$arr['col1']` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a multi dimensional array, or an array where each element is another array. So you'll need to loop twice. Try this to look at it:

```
foreach($array_names as $arr)
{
  foreach($arr as $key => $val)
  {
    print "$key = $val\n";
  }
}
```

Or, to get your just added desired output, do this:

```
foreach($array_names as $arr)
{
  foreach($arr as $key => $val)
  {
    print "$val ";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Or this:

```
foreach($array_names as $arr)
{
   print $arr['ID'] . " " . $arr['col1'] . "\n";
}
```

or a few other ways but you should be getting the picture.